# QGIS Print Layout scale incorrect w.r.t. physical paper size

Tags: qgis, print-composer, scale

I am making a 200x150 cm map of Berlin to be printed, but I'm having difficulties setting up the right scale in the Print Layout.
The map should cover roughly 30 km horizontally, which corresponds to a scale of 1:15000 for the given paper size. However, when I set the scale of my print layout to that value, a much smaller extent of the map is displayed. When I resize it to fit the whole of Berlin (~50 km) though, the calculated scale is 1:40,000, which at a paper width of 2m would be equivalent to 80 km. Is this a bug or am I forgetting something?

This map at 1:15000 scale and 2 m paper width covers roughly 18 km horizontally,...

[image: Print Layout at 1:15000 scale and 2 m paper width]

... while this map at 1:40000 scale and 2 m paper width covers roughly 50 km horizontally.

[image: Print Layout at 1:40000 scale and 2 m paper width]